# Custom Locale - English Display - FRENCH DateFormat

Tags: java, locale

I am working on existing web project based on Struts2. we use message*.properties for i18n. 
 Lastly, we have a client that want to use English for label and French for date format.

My question : Is there a local that matches this need?

if not, how can I customize a Locale?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I used en-GB Locale that matches the need of client